# Formatter for generating ppml file from xml

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

Need a ppml generator from (XML and XSL) or from (FO) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for PPML to XML/XSL(FO) I'm using XEP (http://renderx.com)

Comment: Great, thank you. I have found out the trial version, and it works :))). It is what I need, thank you again.

Comment: @Vardges - The XSL list that is run by Mulberry Technologies is a great resource; especially the archives. http://mulberrytech.com/xsl/xsl-list/subscribe-unsubscribe.html Also, don't forget to accept user493216's answer :-)